# Setting pseudo fields (fl) in Solrj

Tags: java, solr, groovy, solrj

I want to use a pseudo field to return the distance from the center of my solr (geo) spatial search, like it's explained here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#geodist_-_The_distance_function when it says:

> Returning the distance
>
> Solr4.0
>
> You can use the pseudo-field feature to return the distance along with the stored fields of each document by adding fl=geodist() to the request. Use an alias like fl=*dist*:geodist() to make the distance come back in the *dist* pseudo-field instead. Here is an example of sorting by distance ascending and returning the distance for each document in *dist*.
>
> ...&q=*:*&sfield=store&pt=45.15,-93.85&sort=geodist() asc&fl=*dist*:geodist()

Now, I'm using `solrj` (4.5.1) and I can't find a way to set the `fl=_dist_:geodist()` part properly. I can actually manage to add it to the solrQuery object doing:

```
solrQuery.setParam('fl', '_dist_:geodist()')
```

with no compilation errors, but for some reason this is messing up my returned documents.

Any ideas how it should be done?

Ps. code is in `groovy` language, don't freak out for no semi-colons or string within single quotes :)

*** UPDATE ***

Setting the `fl` param as explained above, actually results in returning documents which only contains the `_dist_` field!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few minutes of search, i found this article: http://solr.pl/en/2011/11/22/solr-4-0-new-fl-parameter-functionalities-first-look/

It explains how to return the new alias field(s) in addition to all other parameters, simply like this (please note the * part):

```
fl=*,stock:sum(stockMain,stockShop)
```

So, in my example for `solrj`, it will be:

```
solrQuery.setParam('fl', '*,_dist_:geodist()')
```